# Putting Back button on waze, while navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am opening waze from my app and i want a button which will take me back to my app when clicked, i have already done it for google maps like we have to do as :

```
NSString *urlString = @"comgooglemaps-x-callback://";
NSString *backButton =@"&x-success=MyApp://?resume=true&x-source=MyApp";

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString:urlString]])  
{

urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"comgooglemaps-x-callback://?daddr=%@%@", [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", 
address] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],backButton];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

}
```

Can something like be done in waze?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSString *stringURL = @"waze://?ll=37.331689,-122.030731&z=10";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: i am able to open the waze with the location, but what i want is to have a back button into the waze which will take me to my application

Comment: You can't do that... iOS 9 will allow to go back to the previous app with a button in the top left of your screen, but that's the only possible thing.

Comment: Well i guess then it is the google api which is allowing a back button to the google map, using `comgooglemaps-x-callback:`